# Getting error - No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I have an interface named `IJobService`**

```
@Service
public interface IJobService {
    List<SearchTupleModel> getTuplesFromJobService(List<String> jobIds);
}
```

**I have a class `JobService` implementing this:**

```
@Service
public class JobService implements IJobService {
}
```

In a controller, I am just autowiring this interface as:

```
public class JobSearchResource {
    @Autowired
    IJobService iJobService;
}
```

**But I am getting the error:**

> No qualifying bean of type
>   `e` available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: How your Spring context is initialized, by xml or annotations? Make sure that `JobService` can be accessed via package scan

Comment: It is pure annotation bused, no XML

Comment: u need to define by using @Config classes

Comment: Remove @Service annotation from the IJobService. You only need to annotate the Implementation

Comment: add @Controller for JobSearchresource

Comment: rename IJobService to JobService and JobService to JobServiceImpl and remove @Service from IJobService

Answer (score 3):

Remove @Service annotation from the Interface IJobService.

```
public interface JobService {
    List<SearchTupleModel> getTuplesFromJobService(List<String> jobIds);
}


@Service
public class JobServiceImpl implements JobService {
}
```

And add @Controller to your controller

```
@Controller
public class JobSearchResource {
   @Autowired
   JobService jobService;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your project **Application.java**(or some other name) file which is containing the main method should be in the root directory as shown in the given reference:

[image: sample spring boot project structure]

Application.java file should contain the annotation **@SpringBootApplication** which will automatically scan all the files and create beans for them if they are annotated with **@Service**, **@Controller**, **@Configuration** etc...

Or else if you want to keep the Application.java file in some other package then you have to explicitly mention the root directory in the component scan annotation as shown below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.starterkit.springboot.brs"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

This class configure a spring bean

```
@Configuration
public class IJobServiceConfig {
   @Bean 
   public IJobService iJobService (){
       return new IJobService ();
   }
}
```

also Add `@Controller` for controller class

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove **@Service** above your interface IJobService ?

@Service indicates the code below is candidate for injection.

Since both IJobService and JobService have @Service, it yields 2 choices so spring does not know which one to use.

Comment: if there were 2 beans created, exception text is another, like `found 2 candidates: .... `

Comment: @AlexSalauyou I agree. Interface are not to be instancied. Sorry.
Nevertheless, there is a need to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove @Service annotation from the interface, also define your JobSearchResource bean using @Component or @Controller if its controller.